# WAMP Server 2.4 loading PHP_COM_DONET.dll

Tags: php, com, wamp

I'm trying to enable the php_com_donet.dll extension within PHP. When I check-mark the extension to be enabled WAMP (v2.4) restarts but then I get this error saying that the module could not be found.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded WAMP 2.4 (which was the most recent version at the time I downloaded) and was experiencing issues with loading the com_donet library so I uninstalled 2.4 and installed 2.5 By default it enabled the extension. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the php.ini file you will see that the extension line for php_com_dotnet.dll does not actually exists.

Use the wampmanager icon to edit php.ini

```
wampmanager -> PHP -> php.ini
```

Add this line with all the other similiar `extension` lines they are pretty much in alphbetcial order.

```
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
```

Restart the Apache service

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Restart Service
```

You should now have the extension loaded.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but WAMP is still unable to load the library. I have added the extension line to the correct area within the PHP.ini file but when I restart it, it doesn't list the extension in the localhost. When I put it offline and then online I get the error same as before.

Comment: I suppose you did check that there was actually a php_com_dotnet.dll in the `c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.16/ext` folder? Also exactly what version of WAMPServer are you using? **Add that info to your question**.

Comment: Yes, the php_com_donet.dll exists within the ext folder. I'm using WAMP 2.4